# Highlight CpG sites with Texshade

Tags: sequence-alignment, methylation, visualization

I am using Texshade to produce figures for MSA. Upon reading the documentation I could not find anyway to highlight how conserved CpG sites within the alignment. Does anyone know if this is possible? If not is there another MSA visualizer I can use that can produce a figure like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution I could find was to use the `\shaderegion` function on all the sequences so it ended up looking something like this:

```
\shaderegion{1}{CG}{Red}{OrangeRed}

\shaderegion{2}{CG}{Red}{OrangeRed}

...
```

Then I cast the rest of shading similarity to grey so the CG pairs were more easily distinguishable.

```
\shadingcolors{grays}
```

Two examples one with `\fingerprints` and one regular.
[image]

[image]